# How to run a node app with no listening port in Heroku

Tags: heroku

I have a node app that does a simple web scraping in real time.
Since it has no back-end feature, it doesn't listen any port and never use Express.
When I deploy this app, Heroku automatically runs some commands to build and run my app.

This is my package.json file.

```
"scripts": {
    "develop": "nodemon --exec babel-node src",
    "test": "mocha --require babel-core/register",
    "build": "rimraf lib && babel src -d lib",
    "start": "node lib",
    "lint": "eslint src"
  }
```

I checked the Heroku logs to see if the app is running properly but I found errors like below.

```
...

2020-12-27T07:24:48.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-12-27T07:25:46.564866+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2020-12-27T07:25:46.589773+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2020-12-27T07:25:46.680704+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2020-12-27T07:25:46.732427+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-12-27T07:25:46.735872+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-12-27T07:25:51.844095+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2020-12-27T07:25:54.728760+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-12-27T07:25:54.728776+00:00 app[web.1]: > my-node-app@0.1.0 start /app
2020-12-27T07:25:54.728777+00:00 app[web.1]: > node lib
2020-12-27T07:25:54.728777+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-12-27T07:26:52.296540+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2020-12-27T07:26:52.315003+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2020-12-27T07:26:52.410290+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2020-12-27T07:26:52.468187+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

It seems building was successful but has failed when running it.
In my opinion, Heroku tried to bind PORT but my app never listened any port, so these errors had occurred.
How can I run my app successfully with no error on Heroku in this case?

Comment: Do you have a Proc file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your node.js project is a web server, you cannot remove the port. No port, no web server. Trying to make a web server without a port is like trying to make a locomotive with no railroad.

You can use the default port however. When users give browsers URLs without ports, they automatically apply the default port.

Heroku also provide the default port so you don't have to specify the port
Just deploy your app and use the url provided by the heroku to call node js application